# Browser asking user to login during an SSO re-direct to Idp on the network (SAML)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, service-provider

I've been tasked with implementing SSO at my company. We are using Sp-initiated SSO using SAML. I've set up an internal IIS 7 hosted Idp that is able to talk with SalesForce.com SP (exchanged the certs, configured the web.config file to use windows authentication, all of that good stuff).

Our org is using active directory, so I've set up IIS to use windows authentication (disabled anonymous authentication) with NTLM as the only provider. Our IIS also has SSL enabled as well.

Now when I hit the salesforce website as the user, it re-directs to our Idp as expected. However, I immediately get a prompt in the browser asking me to login. This is not the desired behavior, we want the user to be authenticated seamlessly and re-directed back to salesforce.

When I hit the url of our Idp directly from my computer, it recognizes that I am logged-in to the domain, but that is not the case when accessed from salesforce via SAML SSO. To fix the problem, I added the Idp server to the Trusted Sites in IE. This ends up working as "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" is enabled in IE's Advanced->Security setting. Chrome also ends up working (since it looks like it takes IE's Trusted Site settings?). However, FireFox is not working.

I was wondering if anyone knows why the browser does not recognize that the Idp is on the domain when re-directed from salesforce. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the right config options to FF just like the other browsers so it knows which sites to trust.

Type "about:config" in the address bar and search for "negotiate" from the list of options. You may need to play around a bit to ensure you get the right behavior but you should at least add your site or domain to the "network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris". You can search the web for detailed explanations of each option in the list. Here's a FF article to help get you started as well -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Integrated_Authentication

HTH,
Ian

Comment: Thanks Ian, that worked perfectly on my machine. Is there a way I can apply this in a group policy and have it sent out to the rest of the users?

Comment: I'm fairly certain FireFox does not have any native support for Group Policies. There might be some 3rd Party add-ons that can help.

Comment: That's what I thought. I found a third party solution (called PolicyPak) that claims to allow the management of FF using GP. Most of our users use IE anyways, I thought there might be a workaround for FF.